# React Router returns to homepage on refresh but url stays the same

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router v6, and I am trying to create routes dynamically from an array, the problem is when I go to any other route like '/tech' for example when I refresh it returns me to the homepage and the URL stays the same. how can I fix that? I want the app to stay on /tech on refresh

```
<Routes>
 {this.state.categories.map((category) => {
                                    return (
                                        <Route
                                            key={category.name}
                                            path={`${
                                                category.name === "all" ? "/" : `${category.name}`
                                            }`}
                                            exact
                                            element={
                                                <PLP/>
                                            }
                                        />
                                    );
                                })}
```

these are all the routes rendered in my app if that is of any help

```
<Routes>
    {this.state.categories.map((category) => {
    return (
    <Route
        key={category.name}
        path={`${
        category.name === "all" ?"/" : `/${category.name}`}`}
        exact
        element={<PLP/>}
        />
        );})}
        <Route
        path="/cart"
        element={<Cart/>}/>
        <Route
        path="/pdp/:productID"
        element={<PDP/>}
        />
</Routes>
```

Answer (score 0):

I forked a template [to obtain a codesandbox reproducing your issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-dynamic-routes-co54p5?file=/src/App.jsx).

Categories are defined as an array of objects:

```js
const categories = [
    {
      name: "all"
    },
    {
      name: "tech"
    },
    {
      name: "fruits"
    }
  ];
```

and the routes are dynamically created from the `categories` array.

```
<Routes>
      {categories.map((category) => {
        return (
          <Route
            key={category.name}
            path={`${category.name === "all" ? "/" : `${category.name}`}`}
            exact
            element={
              <>
                <Navbar links={categories} />
                <main>
                  <h4>Current page:</h4>
                  <p>{category.name}</p>
                </main>
              </>
            }
    </Routes>
```

For testing purposes, the `Navbar` component allows you to change routes through Links that are created using the same array of categories.

However after refreshing the page, **it stays on the current page as expected**.

#### Behaviour

- click on tech link
- url change to "/tech"
- renders the `tech` text
- refresh
- url stays the same
- renders the `tech` text

Maybe the problem isn't in this part of the code or I misunderstood.

I hope this has been helpful to you.

I will be happy to know more.